# R - merge/join one data frame to multiple data frames separately

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have seen several threads that merge more than one dataframe into one "master" dataframe, but instead I want to take one reference dataframe and apply it to several other dataframes while keeping the other dataframes separate. I have tried using lapply and 'for' loops, but haven't figured out how to do it. (Disclaimer: I'm new to R.)

df_geo is the reference dataframe and looks something like this:

```
district sector cell    village  village_code
west    sectorA cellA   villageA    XXXXXXXX
west    sectorA cellA   villageB    XXXXXXXX
west    sectorB cellB   villageC    XXXXXXXX
south   sectorC cellC   villageD    XXXXXXXX
```

There are three other datasets that have many more columns with information specific to the type of data they contain, i.e. distribution, survey, follow-up. Every dataset has columns for district, sector, cell, and village (identically named). For example:

```
> df_distr
v1  district sector cell    village     v2  v3  …
..  west    sectorA cellA   villageA    ..  ..  …
..  west    sectorA cellA   villageB    ..  ..  …
..  west    sectorB cellB   villageC    ..  ..  …
..  south   sectorC cellC   villageD    ..  ..  …
```

and

```
> df_survey
v1  v5  v6  district sector  cell   village     v7  …  
..  ..  ..  west    sectorA cellA   villageA    ..  ..
..  ..  ..  west    sectorA cellA   villageB    ..  ..
..  ..  ..  west    sectorB cellB   villageC    ..  ..
..  ..  ..  south   sectorC cellC   villageD    ..  ..
```

Each dataframe has a different number of columns and the location variables are not in the same numerical columns in each. Each district-sector-cell-village combination is unique as is each village_code. I am trying to add a village_code column to each of the three dataframes that records the 8-digit numeric location ID based on the district-sector-cell-village match. Ideally, I would like the column to be appended to each original dataframes (instead of stored in a list). Thus, I'd like them to look like this:

```
> df_distr
v1  district sector cell    village     v2  v3  …  village_code
..  west    sectorA cellA   villageA    ..  ..  …    XXXXXXXX
..  west    sectorA cellA   villageB    ..  ..  …    XXXXXXXX
..  west    sectorB cellB   villageC    ..  ..  …    XXXXXXXX
..  south   sectorC cellC   villageD    ..  ..  …    XXXXXXXX

> df_survey
v1  v5  v6  district sector  cell   village     v7  …  village_code
..  ..  ..  west    sectorA cellA   villageA    ..  ..   XXXXXXXX
..  ..  ..  west    sectorA cellA   villageB    ..  ..   XXXXXXXX
..  ..  ..  west    sectorB cellB   villageC    ..  ..   XXXXXXXX
..  ..  ..  south   sectorC cellC   villageD    ..  ..   XXXXXXXX
```

I can successfully do this one-by-one using code such as `df_distr <- left_join(df_distr, df_geo, by = c("district", "sector", "cell", "village"))` but I'd like a way to do more efficiently.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to left join every dataset with the reference dataset so that all of them have `village_code` attached?

Comment: @useR yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of `data.table`'s modify by reference property to attach the `village_code` column without reassigning the dataframes:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df_geo)
setDT(df_distr)
setDT(df_survey)

lapply(list(df_distr, df_survey), 
       function(x) x[df_geo, village_code := i.village_code, 
                     on=.(district, sector, cell, village)])
```

Notice that `df_distr` and `df_survey` gets printed out, as a result of `lapply`, but the data.frames themselves were successfully modified in place. If you only want the side effect of `:=`, you can use `purrr::walk`, which works like `lapply/map`, but suppresses output:

```
library(purrr)
walk(list(df_distr, df_survey), ~ .[df_geo, village_code := i.village_code,
                                    on=.(district, sector, cell, village)])
```

Note that this method is also much faster than reassigning because there is no copying when modifying the data.frames in place.

**Result:**

```
> df_distr
   v1 district  sector  cell  village v2 v3 village_code
1: ..     west sectorA cellA villageA .. ..     XXXXXXXX
2: ..     west sectorA cellA villageB .. ..     XXXXXXXX
3: ..     west sectorB cellB villageC .. ..     XXXXXXXX
4: ..    south sectorC cellC villageD .. ..     XXXXXXXX

> df_survey
   v1 v5 v6 district  sector  cell  village v7 village_code
1: .. .. ..     west sectorA cellA villageA ..     XXXXXXXX
2: .. .. ..     west sectorA cellA villageB ..     XXXXXXXX
3: .. .. ..     west sectorB cellB villageC ..     XXXXXXXX
4: .. .. ..    south sectorC cellC villageD ..     XXXXXXXX
```

**Data:**

```
df_geo = read.table(text = "district sector cell    village  village_code
west    sectorA cellA   villageA    XXXXXXXX
                    west    sectorA cellA   villageB    XXXXXXXX
                    west    sectorB cellB   villageC    XXXXXXXX
                    south   sectorC cellC   villageD    XXXXXXXX", header = TRUE)

df_distr = read.table(text = "v1  district sector cell    village     v2  v3
..  west    sectorA cellA   villageA    ..  ..
..  west    sectorA cellA   villageB    ..  ..
..  west    sectorB cellB   villageC    ..  ..
..  south   sectorC cellC   villageD    ..  ..", header = TRUE)


df_survey = read.table(text = "v1  v5  v6  district sector  cell   village     v7  
..  ..  ..  west    sectorA cellA   villageA    ..
..  ..  ..  west    sectorA cellA   villageB    ..
..  ..  ..  west    sectorB cellB   villageC    ..
..  ..  ..  south   sectorC cellC   villageD    ..", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say I have a group of four data frames.  `reference` is a stand-in for df_geo and the `tab*` data frames represent the unknown tables you're working with.

```
reference = data.frame(key = letters[1:10],value = 1:10)
tab1 = data.frame(journey = LETTERS[1:3],key=letters[1:3])
tab2 = data.frame(trip = LETTERS[7:10],key=letters[7:10])
tab3 = data.frame(destination = LETTERS[4:8],key=letters[4:8])
```

The goal is to join `reference` to each other data frame.

```
output = lapply(list(tab1=tab1,tab2=tab2,tab3=tab3),left_join,reference,by="key")
```

Here I make a named list (important) of the `tab*` data frames and use `lapply` to apply the same function to each of them, `left_join` in this case.  After I specify the function, I can provide the other necessary arguments to the function - in this case, the table to join (`reference`) and the `by="key"` to indicate how they should be joined.

This returns a list of data frames, but it seems like you want them assigned back to the global environment.

```
lapply(names(output),function(x){
  assign(x,value=output[[x]],envir=globalenv())
})
```

This time when we use `lapply` we do it to the names of output (which are the names we assigned in the previous step.  We `assign` to the name the value of `output` with that name into the global environment.

Now all the `tab*` data frames have been updated and all we had to do to make it happen was write a named list of the data frames in need of updating.